# Is the Fork/Join framework a bad match for the Java 8 Streams API?

Tags: lambda

Today I found an [article](http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html) about Java8's Fork/Join-Framework and its usage for the parallel streams implementation. While I do understand the article, I'm not entirely sure what I should think of it.

Basically what it says it that F/J in conjunction with streams is next to useless, and especially so in the context of JEE applications. Quite a few specific  arguments are listed, such as:

> - it needs a massive volume of easily separable data (aggregate),
> - creates copious threads without regard for others,
> - has a high potential for stack overflows,
> - has a high potential for massive memory usage,
> - has a very, very narrow performance window,
> - is only designed for one request at a time.

Moreover, it gives these arguments against F/J's recursive decompostion approach:

> Recursive decomposition has an even narrower performance window. In addition to the above dynamic decomposition, recursive decomposition optimized for dyadic recursive division only works well:
>
> - on balanced tree structures (Directed Acyclic Graphs)
> - where there are no cyclic dependencies
> - where the computation duration is neither too short nor too long
> - where there is no blocking.

Since this is the only source I could find which complains about FJ, I'm not sure if this can be taken seriously. Are the above-cited, or other similar points a valid concern?

More specifically, does Oracle have an official position regarding the limitations of the F/J Framework as applied to the parallelization of streams processing? If so, does it have plans to do something about them?

Comment: Since I wrote the articles (there is a part I and a pdf now) perhaps you should ask me the question directly. There is an email address with the article. In any case, Streams work beautifully. Parallel support relies on a dyadic recursive division method that is usually unsuitable for general-purpose usage. The alternative is paraquental processing which significantly slows down the process and cannot scale. That's about all I can say in this comment.

Comment: @edharned Why do you refrain from writing an answer, which would be of interest to the general public? I've read the PDF some time ago and the problem is that it isn't very accessible. If you could write an answer which would be short enough and didn't use terms unfamiliar to the general reader, it would be a great contribution.

Comment: @edharned The thing is that I and my colleagues cannot really understand what's the problem is. We were able to speed things up almost linear to the number of cores when doing pure collection computations. And the parallel array sort works also very good. Your article and your comments al over the internet are really not easy to understand because you describe the problem very generally without even going into detail or showing an alternative. ALSO: You keep saying that C# is "much better" because it has a "parallel engine". Every time I read this I'm quite sure your are a troll.

Comment: @edharned Because C# is nowhere better in this regard. Actually almost all C# + Parallel demos run slower (much slower!) instead of faster on my machine. But this may be related to mono, poor mono =/. So please: If you continue posting this stuff please give us a little bit more detail about what's wrong without being the anti-research-guy. Be objective and friendly, do not pursue other people's work. And make your point clear without dancing around it. Thanks.

Comment: It is noteworthy that three of the five voters to close this question come from the core Oracle Java team---even though that same Oracle  team *does* have an official position on this subject, by definition making the question not "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: There is nothing in the article about C# other than it uses the .Net framework for parallel processing. That .Net framework is a thread container, which the F/J framework desperately needs.
@Marko give me an example. The answers are on hold.

Comment: @edharned Please explain what you mean with thread container. Java uses pthreads and .Net windows threads. Both are native threads which are managed by the OS.

Comment: @KrOe This is an old article http://coopsoft.com/ar/J2SEArticle.html The idea of containing threads goes back a long way. Essentially, it means to manage threads.

Comment: @edharned Ok, now I understand what you are saying about C#. Though C# has native threads, the ThreadPool impl. used by AsParallel() kind of watches(manages) it's threads. But as I understand, Java' ThreadPoolExecutor does this, too, doesn't it ? I mean, broken threads, are restarted, you have tasks to queue etc. But you complained about the ForkJoinPool so I looked into it and also saw basic recovery techniques. Isn't this also kind of managed ? Maybe not as sophisticated as other options but at least it's managed.

Comment: @edharned I honestly can't see any difference between .NET ThreadPool and Java's ThreadPoolExecutor class. Those are basically equal. So you are saying that stream.parallel() should have be implemented on top of ThreadPoolExecutor (aka Executors.***) ?

Comment: @Kr0e All I am saying is that the threads, and their management, belong outside the application JDK. Compensation threads are for amateurs. The way to handle excessive task blocking is to time the thread when it calls the user task. When the time is over a limit then perform a pre-determined procedure: alert someone or some program, expunge the thread and perhaps replace it, etc. Having that function underneath is far better than within a single application.

Comment: @edharned So what you propose is the thread container as a separate process? That means the whole state needed for computation must go through the serialize-deserialize cycle, introducing an unconditional overhead for each kind of task, which scales linearly with the size of input (often huge)---and output as well.

Comment: Also, when you kill a thread which takes to long, the entire process must be deemed compromised. In your idea do you restart the whole thread container at that point? And generally, your idea seems to make this timout event a *failure*, whereas compensation threads make it a *nuisance*, at least in the more benign cases.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik 1. A container embedded within the JVM, or excellent thread management within the program. 2. You can't kill a thread. The best you can do is mark its management structure as expunged so if it does resume it can die quickly and have a procedure to notify someone or some program that may replace it with a new thread. Compensation threads just spit out more and more threads indiscriminately.

Comment: @edharned 1. So you want a JDK-provided thread container, after all? Can you please pinpoint exactly how ForkJoinPool's common pool misses the mark? 2. If you mark the thread as unusable, leaving it to die on its own, then clearly you must start a new thread to keep on going. Or do you propose to go on crippled, with N-1 threads? 3. Could you explain in plain language what you mean by "marking its management structure as expunged?"

Comment: Reviewing your comment more carefully, perhaps you mean that the "procedure to notify someone or some program" runs immediately, not when the blocking thread wakes. And the point would be that this "someone" has the choice whether to start a replacement thread (what F/J does), or handle the situation differently? So basically, F/J should have a callback for that, similar to ThreadPoolExecutor's `rejectedExecutionHandler`? If so, that doesn't seem like a design flaw, merely a missing feature.

Comment: Yes. I've been doing task parallelism with F/J for about 30 years now, 4 years with data parallelism. If you'd like to see how this works then have a look at the data parallel open-source project I maintain on source.forge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse

Comment: @edharned Rest assured that your credentials have not gone unnoticed. In fact, they play against you to some degree: your criticism of Lea's F/J is quite evidently a head-to-head comparison with your work, where you just present the advantages of your approach as criticism of Lea's. It is difficult to anyone from outside to validate any particular point you are making because you do not provide sufficient justification. I understand that all those points seem obvious to you, but the truth may easily come out as more faceted than you see it from your unique vantage point.

Comment: @edharned As an example, I have tried to validate your claim "Paraquential processing makes simple summation such as
`Arrays.stream().parallel().map(e -> e * 5 ).sum();` run about ten times slower than a simple two thread split." I have confirmed that indeed it is slow; however that barely scratches the surface of a full, convincing *diagnosis* of its slowness. I have changed the code slightly so that the calculation is more complicated (using `Math.pow` on `double`s), and suddenly the behavior got a lot better. I could make no connection to your claim about the cause.

Comment: Also the JVM does all kinds of crazy optimizations. @Edharned While that what you are saying kind of makes sense I have not experienced any of the issues you are talking about in REAL world. In real world parallel() often does a very good job in speeding thinga up. Often equal to the numbers cores i have. The thing is that parallelism comes with a cost and the work you are doing must be complex enough so that the tradeoff of multicore goes to 0.

Comment: @Kr0e But note that, if you have 1,000,000 ints to sum on four cores, theoretically there should be no problem feeding each core with 250,000 and leaving it to do its work undisturbed. My results point to *per lambda invocation* overhead which does not manifest in the sequential case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i think you have to make sure that the Stream is unordered(). This is documented for the parallell() funtcion.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik https://gist.github.com/chrisprobst/1e81fb09962d43814895 This is not very memory efficient but it shows that the speedup is = number of cores. The important part here is that an existing array is easily parallelizable. I guess if you make an unordered generated stream the speed up may be equal.

Comment: I am using `jmh`, https://gist.github.com/mtopolnik/453729c02b47d9485128. `unordered()` doesn't seem to be necessary---the stream is already unordered. Anyway, I see less than 2x speedup with 4 cores.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the gist of the problems with the application of F/J in the implementation of the Streams API:

1. F/J is good for the parallelization of in-memory, random-access structures: it wants to be able to divide the full problem top-down, by recursively halving it into two subproblems of equal size;
2. the *stream* paradigm is primarily about the processing of lazily materialized, sequential data sources, which can only be divided into *a sequence of chunks*, and the number of chunks is usually not known in advance.

While F/J can be bent somewhat to support sequential chunking, this is perceived by it as "anomalous" and "lopsided", eventually giving rise to insurmountable issues when combined with the unpredictable I/O latency in reading those chunks<sup>1</sup>.

Streams API excels at the parallelization of in-memory structures and is usually helpful with the processing of lazy, I/O-backed streams, but it fails when you try to combine these two features in a single use case.

If you have a loop in your code which introduces a CPU-bound bottleneck, it is fairly likely that this loop is iterating over the contents of some file, network request, or rows of an SQL result set. None of these targets for parallelization get support from the Streams API.

The official position is that this use case is not supported because the Streams API has a different, equally legitimate focus. In the department of lazy parallel streams, this focus amounts to stream sources which are *calculated* from data existing within working memory, with the additional constraint that these sources must be *unordered*—that each member can be calculated independently, without the need to first calculate any other. An example of such a stream is a range of integers, but a stream of random numbers from an LCG is already outside of the area being focused on by the API, because these random numbers can only be generated sequentially.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Keep in mind that this is the **official** statement. I have personally not yet hit this issue, having instead successfully parallelized the processing of my I/O sources.*

Comment: Actually, SplittableRandom has great parallel random number generation -- and a good Stream implementation.

Comment: That's because there is much more to SplittableRandom than an LCG.